# 2-byte checksum

Tags: encodings, crc, checksum

I cannot figure out what checksum is used for the following communication.
As I understand, `450D` is the “stop” part. It doesn't change no matter what. And the two bytes before `450D` are the “checksum”.

I tried all checksum calculators. Nothing works.

```
530D0018BCFFFF038B00000006A11E3D0700002204040932FFFFFFB3450D
530D0018BCFFFF038B0000001A7F61920700002204040932FFFFFF3D450D
530D0018BCFFFF038B00000006A11E3D0E00002204040932FFFFFFBA450D
530D0018BCFFFF038B00000006A11E3D0E00002204040932753081E3450D
530D0018BCFFFF038B00000006A11E3D0E00012204060932753081E6450D
530D0018BCFFFF038B0000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF38450D

530D0104D3FFFFD1450D
530D0102DDDD450D
530D0007C0FFFF010808CF450D
530D0006C2FFFFF30CBF450D
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to re.se. It'd be great if you could add more details in the question - where is this data from? What device is sending it? over what medium? Why do you think its a checksum? This would help us understand better about the problem you are facing. The question in its current state is likely to be marked "need details" and closed.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what type of CRC-8 this is. I tried everything and I found the solution. Please, see the code below. It works if you do not take 4 first bytes into calculation.

Maybe it will help someone.

```
static string CalcCrc(byte[] input)
{
    int crc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        crc += input[i];
    crc &= 0xff;
    string crchex = crc.ToString("X2");
    return crchex;
}
```